# Putting more coding logic in array/json vs. class method calls

Tags: php, arrays, json, class

When working with PHP, I notice it's popular nowadays for class libraries to use lots of "prep" method calls that build up to an action. E.g.:

```
$db = new database();

$result = $db->select("*")
   ->from("table1")
   ->where(["field3" => "apple"])
   ->orderBy("field4")
   ->run();
```

I can see the benefits this gives you when using an IDE with autocomplete. But I also see advantages to putting this information into one array that gets passed at once. E.g.:

```
$queryParams = [
    "fields"     => "*",
    "table"      => "table1",
    "constraint" => ["field3" => "apple"],
    "sort"       => "field4",
];

$db = new database();
$result = $db->select($queryParams);
```

The advantage I see is that the information is treated as one unit and is easy to pass around. It could be stored as JSON in a file or table, unserialized, and with one statement the information gets processed. Also, it's less intermingled with PHP code; if I want to convert my project from one language/framework to another, if a good part of the information that makes up my project is already in compatible JSON, then it will be easier for me to do so.

I understand that I could easily write up my own code that iterates over $queryParams and passes the values to the proper method calls, but I am curious why passing all the information a class needs to run an action at once is not good practice.

Comment: why you tag it in  JavaScript

Comment: It's not really a PHP specific question, even though the example is PHP, and the pattern is similar to jQuery. If you have better ideas for keywords let me know.

Comment: there is no classes in js

Comment: You could achieve the same pattern with prototyping in javascript but since this seems a point of confusion I will just remove the javascript tag.